# Two vectors $x,y$ whose Kendall´s tau is zero but there exists a function $g$ such that $y=g(x)$

Tags: correlation, kendall-tau

I need to construct two $10$ X $1$ vectors $\overrightarrow{x}, \overrightarrow{y}$, such that Kendall´s $\tau $ is zero but there exists a function $g$ such that $\overrightarrow{y} = g(\overrightarrow{x})$.

I understand that I need the same amount of concordant and discordant pairs $(x_i,y_i)$ for Kendall´s $\tau$ to be zero but I cannot think of a function $g$ that can guarantee this condition.

Also, I suspect $\overrightarrow{x}=(-4,-3,-2,-1,0,0,1,2,3,4)$ and $\overrightarrow{y}=g(\overrightarrow{x})=\overrightarrow{x}^2$ might work but I don´t know how to rigorously prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is correct. In fact any symmetric function applied to the vector you defined would work.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to prove it is just by calculation. Work out $\tau$. It is zero.

More generally than the $10\times 1$ case, consider the transformation $X\to -X$.
This switches a positive association to a negative one, so $\tau_{\textrm{before}}= - \tau_{\textrm{after}}$.

On the other hand, the transformation leaves the joint distribution $(X,Y)$ unchanged, so $\tau$ must be the same before and after the transformation.

The only way to get both is to have $\tau=0$.